# When do you use table_list?

Tags: r

I have this r chunk in rstudio:

```
library(rvest)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

page <- "https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/indian-liver-patient-records"
XPATH <- '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div'
table_list <- 
  page %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = XPATH) %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

Indian_Liver_Patient <- table_list[[1]]

str(Indian_Liver_Patient)
```

Then I am getting an error that says:

```
Error in table_list[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: When I try your code, `table_list` is empty, meaning it didn't find any nodes matching your `xpath` - you may have to tweak your `xpath` or find a different way of grabbing the required element (e.g. by ID).